# Big clear sticker for shop front window - advice

Tags: print-design, resolution, vinyl

Having a new job to do which is a big illustration, 1200mm X 2400mm high for a shop front window to be printed onto clear vinyl, a big sticker.

The linework will be quite bold, eg  5 - 20mm thick, in some places full block colour (all white).

Was going to try and tackle this in PSD at full size at 150dpi.

Has anyone done this type of work before and can advise on anything to make note off when creating the artwork?

Comment: The first thing you should always do when starting a new print project is to visit the printer's website or call them to know what are their specific requirements. A sticker or vinyl can be printed using different methods; we don't know which one. If you really cannot ask your client or printer about this, then search this site for "large format printing" and/or "vinyl printing". Finally, just a (strong) suggestion, what can be done in vector should be done in vector as much as possible!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use vinyl or digitally printed vinyl like [Mactac](http://www.mactac.eu/products-macal-9800-pro-1-11-2001-2001.htm) (which has an 8-10 year outdoor life) contour cut to shape instead of printing on clear vinyl for windows. Contour cut window graphics are supplied with application tape to keep the graphics in place, once removed leaving only the artwork without any clear backing, which tends to catch the light giving unwanted reflections. We always use this method for non-block out window graphics or lettering, see some example cut out [window graphic pictures](http://www.printco.ie/signage/window-graphics/index.html) here.

Mactac has a seriously strong adhesive, which will ensure the thinner 5mm areas of the project hold.

Regarding the artwork, it sounds like the linework could be done in Illustrator as a vector.

If you aren’t familiar with installation, would also suggest getting a fitter to install. Smaller pieces are easier to manage, and there are a lot of great videos on Youtube for installing window graphics but this is a larger size which can be difficult to manage.  Bubbles do not look good in window graphics!